# Assigning property to a string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Following is the javascript code which is returning `undefined` but didn't get why `Javascript` being loosely typed language is returning `undefined`here. What is going on under the hood in memory ?

```js
var myVar = "My String";

myVar.name = "Test"; 

console.log(myVar.name);
```

Answer (score 5):

Primitives [can't have properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) Your assignment is silently failing. Use strict mode to make the error visible.

```js
'use strict';
var myVar = "My String";

myVar.name = "Test"; 

console.log(myVar.name);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'name' on string 'My String'

MDN has a big section on how strict mode can [convert mistakes into errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#converting_mistakes_into_errors).

Comment: A good answer that can become even better if you can add a link to an official documentation page that backs up your statement.